# How to draw path of contour integral enclosing imaginary axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, decorations

I have practically no experience with Tikz but was able to piece together this diagram of a contour integral enclosing the imaginary axis.

[image]

It was produced with this code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    % Axes:
    \draw [->] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node [above left]  {$\re(p_0)$};
    \draw [->] (0,-4.7) -- (0,4.7) node [below left = -1pt] {$\im(p_0)$};

    % Axes labels:
    \foreach \n in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}{%
        \draw[fill] (0,\n) circle (1pt) node [right] {$i \omega_{_{\n}}$};
    }
    \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1pt) node [above right] {0};

    % Contour line
    \draw[DarkBlue]
      (1,-4) -> (1,4) node [below right] {$C$} arc (0:180:1) (-1,4) -- (-1,-4) arc (180:360:1);

    \draw[fill] (3,2) circle (1pt) node [pin={above:poles of $h(p_0)$}] {};
    \draw[fill] (2,-2) circle (1pt) node [pin={above right:poles of $h(p_0)$}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There are a few things I'm still struggling with.

1. I would like the two half arcs at the top and bottom to be dashed but the vertical lines connecting them to remain solid.
2. The two `pins` labelling dots outside the contour with `poles of h(p0)` should be just one pin with lines pointing to both dots.
3. I'd like `Im(p0)` to be further removed from the imaginary axis but connected by a thin line just like the pins.
4. The contour should be decorated by a few arrows pointing in the counterclockwise direction.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,svgnames,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, positioning}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
decoration={
markings,% switch on markings
mark=at position .75 with {\arrow{>}}}
                    ]
    % Axes:
    \draw [->] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node [above left]  {$\re(p_0)$};
    \draw [->] (0,-4.7) -- (0,4.7) node [below left = -1pt and 11mm] {$\im(p_0)$};

    % Axes labels:
    \foreach \n in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}{%
        \draw[fill] (0,\n) circle (1pt) node [right] {$i \omega_{_{\n}}$};
    }
    \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1pt) node [above right] {0};

% Contour line
\draw[DarkBlue,postaction={decorate}]   ( 1,-4) -- ( 1, 4) node [below right] {$C$};
\draw[DarkBlue,postaction={decorate}]   (-1, 4) -- (-1,-4);
\draw[DarkBlue,dashed]                  (1,4) arc (0:180:1) (-1,4)  (-1,-4) arc (180:360:1);

\draw[fill] (3, 2) circle (1pt) node[below right=2mm and 9mm] (h0) {poles of $h(p_0)$} 
            (2,-2) circle (1pt);
\draw[thin, shorten >=1mm] (h0.west) --  (3,2) (h0.south west) -- (2,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
let consider first OP comments regarding imaginary axis label:

```
\documentclass[tikz,svgnames,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, positioning}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
decoration={
markings,% switch on markings
mark=at position .75 with {\arrow{>}}},
every pin/.append style = {pin distance=11mm, pin edge={<-,black}}% added
                    ]
% Axes:
\draw [->] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node [above left]  {$\re(p_0)$};
\draw [->] (0,-4.7) -- (0,4.7) node [below left, pin=left: $\im(p_0)$] {};% changed
% Axes labels:
\foreach \n in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}{%
    \draw[fill] (0,\n) circle (1pt) node [right] {$i \omega_{_{\n}}$};
}
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1pt) node [above right] {0};
% Contour line
\draw[DarkBlue,postaction={decorate}]   ( 1,-4) -- ( 1, 4) node [below right] {$C$};
\draw[DarkBlue,postaction={decorate}]   (-1, 4) -- (-1,-4);
\draw[DarkBlue,dashed]                  (1,4) arc (0:180:1) (-1,4)
                                        (-1,-4) arc (180:360:1);

\draw[fill] (3, 2) circle (1pt) node[below right=2mm and 9mm] (h0) {poles of $h(p_0)$}
            (2,-2) circle (1pt);
\draw[thin, shorten >=1mm] (h0.west) --  (3,2) (h0.south west) -- (2,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great! That's exactly what I had in mind, except for one detail. Do you know how to draw a thin line from `Im(p0)` to its axis?

Comment: Also, is there no way to have parts of the contour dashed and parts solid without breaking it up into multiple `\draw` commands?

Comment: (i) to my opinion is better move node closer to y-axis so, that it is inside integral contour .... other wise you can draw line on the same way as it is for poles `h(0)`, (ii) it is possible only with broke line to several parts. If the dashed line parts are on their end, tha they can be joined with `arc`s.