# Imaginary unit automatic setup in tick marks for imaginary axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis, ticks

I have seen solutions like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337310/how-to-draw-path-of-contour-integral-enclosing-imaginary-axis) and [this (in the question section)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18260/drawing-a-circle-in-the-complex-plane), but they don't use the `axis` subenvironment in the `tikzpicture` environment.

If I make a 2-D plot, the ticks, tick marks, and tick spacings appear based on how one sets up the settings, but only "real" numbers appear (if one wants to set up the tick marks such that all the tick marks have π in each of them). I don't mind doing that since π is a real constant.

In the case of the imaginary unit *i* (or *j* in the engineering world), I would like it to appear *automatically* in the tick values on the imaginary axis.

Here is the MWE for functional purposes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, rectangle, 
        minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
    sum/.style={draw, circle, node distance=1cm},
    input/.style={coordinate},
    output/.style={coordinate},
    pinstyle/.style={pin edge={to-,thin,black}}}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                xmin=-20,xmax=5,
                ymin=-5,ymax=5,
%               ytick={-10, -5, 5, 10}, %when axis equal is set
%               yticklabels={$-j10$, $-j5$,  $j5$, $j10$},
                ytick={-4, -2, 2, 4}, %when axis equal is not set
                yticklabels={$-j4$, $-j2$,  $j2$, $j4$},
                axis lines=center,
                axis line style=->, xlabel = {$\sigma$}, ylabel={$j\omega$},
                %axis equal,
                every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south},
                every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west},
                legend cell align={left},
                legend pos=outer north east]
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output (for `axis equal` not set):

[image]

Is there a way to make a setting in the `axis` subenvironment in `tikzpicture` such that when the vertical ticks automatically adjust due to setting changes, the *j* will *automatically* appear to the left of the number (and to the right of the minus sign if the number is negative), or to the right of the number?

Comment: Unrelated, but isn't the imaginary unit denoted `$i$`, at least in mathematics?

Comment: @Bernard Not always. *j* is also used as the imaginary unit sometimes. But I don't understand why writing `j2` instead of `2j` which makes sense to me.

Comment: As far as  I know, that's an engineering notation.

Comment: Hi Bernard, yes, *j* is used in (electrical) engineering. SebGlav, it’s common practice from my experience, especially in electrical engineering.

Comment: As Superman explains, in electrical engineering we use `$j$` instead of `$i$` because `$i$` is reserved for currents. And yes, we write the `$j$` before the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-20, xmax=5,
ymin=-5, ymax=5,
axis lines=center,
xlabel = {$\sigma$}, ylabel={$j\omega$},
every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south},
every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west},
yticklabel={$\pgfmathparse{\tick > 0 ? "j" : "-j"} \pgfmathresult \pgfmathparse{abs(\tick)} {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$},
%yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick} j$}, %This is for j to appear on the right side of the number instead of the left
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with custom y ticks]

Comment: I have a couple of questions: 1. If I'm correct, `\pgfmathparse{\tick > 0 ? "j" : "-j"}` sets the "prefix" for every tick mark, and `\pgfmathresult` prints `$j$` or `$-j$`. Next, `\pgfmathparse{abs(\tick)}` takes the abs value of the tick value, and `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}` prints it out. Is that correct?

Comment: 2. I thought `\pgfmathparse{}` only stores numbers, not strings? Besides numbers and strings (if correct for the latter), what other data types can `\pgfmathparse{}` store?

Comment: 3. In your answer, why is `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}` in a pair of braces? I removed them, and the output worked as fine. In other words, I ran `yticklabel={$\pgfmathparse{\tick > 0 ? "j" : "-j"} \pgfmathresult \pgfmathparse{abs(\tick)} \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$}` and it still worked.

Comment: 1. You are correct. 2. I do not know 3. Just a mistake of mine - probably because I was experimenting to make it work.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: Reading p. 1028 and 1032 in the manual. My understanding is that `\pgfmathparse{}` always works on a string. If the string has double quotes, it will not be parsed.

Comment: "An expression (or part of an expression) surrounded with double quotes (i.e., the character ") will not be evaluated. Obviously this should be used with great care." Great care example bottom of p. 1032